# Как jest считает процент покрытия?

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты, react-native, react-hook, jest

по какому принципу Jest считает процент покрытия? Код покрыт не на 100%, но он выдаёт, что 100% покрытия.
У меня есть файл, в нём есть функция и пару текстов.

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';

function App() {


  function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b;
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      {sum(132, 13)}
      <h1>Привет мир</h1>
      <h2>Привет мир2</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Файл теста

```
   render(<App />);

   const title = screen.getByText('Привет мир');
   expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Как вы видите при тесте, покрытие файл не 100%, но jest выдаёт, что данный файл покрыт на 100% почему так выходит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вопрос отличный. Постараюсь вечером ответить

Comment: Добрый день вопрос отредактирован.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest считает покрытие кода используя плагин `babel-plugin-istanbul`.

Детально как это все работает под капотом можно прочитать [**тут**](https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/3f57448c47c404e12200815048b1cc01). Я не стал все это переводить и добавлять в ответ так как очень много лишнего получится.

И так, переходим к вашему вопросу. У вас все верно. Покрытие кода 100%  потому что функция `sum` вызывается в фазе рендера.

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {sum(132, 13)} // <--
```

Функции которые вызываются на фазе рендера jest считает покрытыми. Можете обычную функцию добавить и даже не вызвать и увидите красную линию означающий что это линия не покрыта тестами.